# JScript.NET Design IDE

Tags: .net, jscript.net

I'm currently using JScript.NET for a small UI application. The problem is that my Visual Studio Express doesn't support JScript.NET for designing the UI. Is there a free IDE that I can use to design my UI and produce valid JScript.NET code?

I just need the IDE Design functionality to Design the application, that's it.

Currently what I'm doing is converting the very similar C# code that it generates, over to JScript.NET, but It's kind of getting annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there doesn't seem to be ANY JScript.NET IDE out there. If you're just looking to design your application, you can just produce the C# or whatever code for the UI and generate a `.dll` out of that. Then you can use that dll from you JScript.NET code.

This is what I'm doing and it works great... it's awesome how you can share dlls across different languages! Loving .NET!

Answer (score 2):

I use the VS2008 c# for designer
it seems to work OK...

i create the Form Design inside VS2008 for c#

i get to the source the designer crated...

Copy and paste into my JScript...

then i have to change the VARs
ex

c#

```
private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;
```

jscript

```
private var webBrowser1 : System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser;
```

i also check the output on compile. just to fix any other conversion problems